# d3 plus Treemap Link

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

Consulta tengo este script que me redirecciona al link dentro del json pero necesito que primero valla al segundo nivel del treemap y luego redireccione, soy nuevo en d3plus alguna ayuda o sugerencia.

necesito configurar el .mouse para que primero recorra los niveles y al llegar al ultimo redireccione al link pasado a través del json

```js
var sample_data = [{
    "CLP": 35198930,
    "Institucion": "I MUNICIPALIDAD DE ALGARROBO",
    "rubro": "I - Hoteles Y Restaurantes",
    "URL": "http://xxxxxxx/Empresa/77012870/5"
  },
  {
    "CLP": 9000000,
    "Institucion": "GOBERNACION PROVINCIAL DE ELQUI",
    "rubro": "I - Hoteles Y Restaurantes",
    "URL": "http://xxxxxxx/Empresa/77012870/7"
  },
  {
    "CLP": 20450792,
    "Institucion": "SUBSECRETARIA DEL DEPORTE",
    "rubro": "H - Comercio Al Por Mayor Y Menor, Rep. Veh.Automotores/Enseres Domesticos ",
    "URL": "http://xxxxxxx/Empresa/77012870/6"
  },
  {
    "CLP": 1000000,
    "Institucion": "FUNDACIÓN CASA DE LA PAZ",
    "rubro": "No Encontrado",
    "URL": "http://xxxxxxx/Empresa/77012870/6"
  },
  {
    "CLP": 500000,
    "Institucion": "HOSPITAL DE LA DIRECCIÓN DE PREVISIÓN DE CARABINEROS DE CHILE",
    "rubro": "D - Industrias Manufactureras No Metalicas",
    "URL": "http://xxxxxxx/Empresa/77012870/6"
  },
]
var visualization = d3plus.viz()
  .container("#viz")
  .data(sample_data)
  .type("tree_map")
  .id(["rubro", "Institucion"])
  .size("CLP")
  .title("OC EN PESOS CHILENOS (CLP) POR RUBRO")
  .mouse({
    "move": true,
    "click": function(node, viz) {

      window.open(node.URL, '_blank', 'fullscreen=yes');

    }
  })
  .draw()
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="//d3plus.org/js/d3plus.js"></script>
<div id="viz"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución a mi pregunta, la publico con el fin de ayudar a otros que puedan tener el mismo problema que yo

```js
.mouse({                
             "move": true,
             "click":function(node, viz){         
             if (node.d3plus.depth == 0){return viz} 
             else {
                 window.open(node.URL, '_blank', 'fullscreen=yes');}
             }
            })
```